# How to remove wrap "[" and "]" in aggregate Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

i'm beginner for studying MongoDB, i have a problem when use aggregate to get results from collection and i really hope someone will help me:

**My code:**

```
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "product_id": "$_id", 
      "product_phone": "$product_phone",
      "product_tablet": "$product_tablet",
      "product_colors": "$product_colors",
      "options": [
        {
          title: "Mobile Phone",
          data: { 
            $ifNull: [ "$product_phone", null ] 
          }
        },
        {
          title: "Tablet",
          data: {
            $ifNull: [ "$product_tablet", null ]
          }
        },    
        {
            $map: {
              input: '$product_colors', 
              in: {
                  "title": "$$this.color",
                  "data": "$$this.photos"
              }                 
            }
        }  

      ] 
    }
  },
```

**The result is (screenshot 1):**

[image]

**But i wanna get result like this (screenshot 2):**

[image]

Who can help me?

Comment: What are the different between those two screenshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$map` returns an array, this is why you're getting the current structure. What you can do is wrap it all with `$concatArrays`, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
       ...
      "options": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          [
            {
              title: "Mobile Phone",
              data: {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$product_phone",
                  null
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              title: "Tablet",
              data: {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$product_tablet",
                  null
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$product_colors",
              in: {
                "title": "$$this.color",
                "data": "$$this.photos"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vc7rkvEbnQz)